# Need Help To Identify Attached SMD Component

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I am trying to fix a RS485 circuit.
There is 3-pin protection components on both A and B pins.
The component is connected serially to the line and mid pin is grounded.
There is no label on the component.

The resistance is nearly 0 ohm and the component is short circuit by defult.

Could you please help to identify this component?

[image: Protection Component]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: Short circuit between which pins?

Comment: the resistance between the firs and third pin is 0.5 ohm.  mid pin is grounded. I heated the component to 300 Celcius but the resistance didnt change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It quite likely is one of the NFE series of Murata.
Looking at the size, I guess [NFE61PT 2706(6816)](https://www.murata.com/en-sg/search/productsearch?cate=luNoiseSupprFilteFeedThroughFilter&partno=NFE61PT).
The chip "EMIFIL" NFE61PT is a **T-type circuit EMI suppression filter**.

Bad quality image from the datasheet reveals the low DC resistance you're measuring between input and output. Therefore, I think it's quite likely the component is **not** broken.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is a EMI suppression filter. But as there are no markings on the device it is impossible to know which exact device it is.

Comment: @Justme True. The same applies to SMD resistors. You never know *exactly* what component has been used. Therefore I wrote: it *quite likely* is *one* of the NFE series. OP should confirm the components dimension with the datasheet's dimensions and could further desolder it and measure the insertion loss using a spectrum analyzer.

Comment: But as I just edited: the component is likely **not** broken, so probably an exact part number isn't required as there is no need to replace the component.

Comment: Indeed, based measurements that component is not the problem.

Comment: @Huisman, thanks for your help. The component is exactly Murata NFE. The part number isn't important because the component is working.